# popup doesn't work correctly on my mobile phone-JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

please any help ?
I'm trying to add popup div to my mobile web app in JQM , but unfortunately the code above doesn't work on my mobile phone , it show the app in tiny at the right corner. but in IE I see it fine.
what i'm doing wrong?

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2" >

        <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic2"  class="ui-content">
            <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="d" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right"  title="close"></a>
            Close
       </div>
</div>
```

and my javascript code:

```
    $("#popupBasic2").popup('open');
```

screenshot:

[image]

any suggestions?
Thanks, MOR

Comment: can you share your complete html file so to identify where your bug is exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what cause this happen . it seems that popup doesn't work on `<html dir="rtl">` the rtl messed it up..

Answer (score 0):

check if you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in your head.

Here is an example my popup:

```
<a href="#popupDelete" data-rel="popup" data-inline="true" data-position-to="window">Delete Bonus</a>

            <div data-role="popup" id="popupDelete" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="c" data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:400px;" class="ui-corner-all">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" class="ui-corner-top">
                <h1>Delete?</h1>
            </div>
                <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
                <h3 class="ui-title">To Delete Bonus?</h3>
                <p>This action cannot be undone.</p>
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow" data-theme="c">Cancel</a>
                <a href="" onclick="deletebonus();" data-role="button" data-inline="true"  data-theme="b" rel="external">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: yes I have it , it's very weird I deleted the "dir='rtl' " from <html> and it's work fine !

Answer (score -1):

u can use  "Bootstrap"  http://getbootstrap.com/

**1.  Include it at the beginning of all your projects.**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**2. For Example:**

```
<button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newModal"></button>

 ->data-target ="#newModal" !! so...find the id named 'newModal'
```

**3. Pop-up**

```
<!-- Modal: there is popup Screen-->
<div class="modal fade" id="newModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">hihihihihi</h4>
    </div>


    <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
   <label for="Name" class="col-md-3 control-label">Name</label>
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myName" name="myName" maxlength="20">
   </div>
    </div>        
   </div><!-- /.modal-body -->

   <div class="modal-footer">
      <label  class="col-md-6 control-label">there is a footer</label>
   </div>

   </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

**Like this**

Sorry i cant post the image!

u can try this link!!  http://images.plurk.com/2Ovvy6BlcrVkFJTGyPLubS.jpg
thx!!